# Compare exact integers greater than "long integer"

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion, comparison

I need to find a better VBA data type in Excel 2013 so I can make a more accurate comparison between two positive 10 digit integers. I've found and tried `CULng`, but this doesn't seem to exist in this version. Also, `CLng` doesn't have the range necessary for these numbers.

I have a database of phone numbers (10 digits) and need a way to compare two exact numbers. Some of the entries in my DB are strings listing the first and last of a range so I can't just use If A = B Then (do something). I've tried using `CSng`, but it rounds the numbers off using exponential format (5555559100 and 5555559150 both become 5.555559e+09 ). The two numbers are then seen as equal even though they don't match. Previous to this code, I have stripped the searching TN down to just the digits but it is still a string value.

```
Private Sub FindTN()

Dim TN As String
Dim begin  As Single
Dim last As Single
Dim RowNo As Long

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "5555559100TO5555559125"
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "5555559150TO5555559175"
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = "5555559160"

TN = "5555559160"

For Each entry In Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
    If Len(entry.Value) = 10 And entry.Value = TN Then
        RowNo = entry.Row
        Debug.Print "RowNo = " & RowNo

    'Find beginning and ending values of a range
    ElseIf Len(entry.Value) > 10 And InStr(11, entry.Value, "TO") = 11 Then
        begin = CSng(Left(entry.Value, 10))
        last = CSng(Right(entry.Value, 10))

        'Search within range
        If CSng(TN) >= begin And CSng(TN) <= last Then
            RowNo = entry.Row
            Debug.Print "RowNo = " & RowNo
        End If
    End If
Next entry

End Sub
```

It should match on Row 2 and 3 only, but instead results in

```
RowNo = 1
RowNo = 2
RowNo = 3
```

Comment: change every thing to a Double and `CSng` to `Cdbl`

Comment: Use the Decimal data type.  With no decimals, can accommodate integers up to 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335

Answer (score 1):

Fix variable as double  like this.

```
Private Sub FindTN()

Dim TN As String
Dim begin  As Double 'Single
Dim last As Double ' Single
Dim RowNo As Long

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "5555559100TO5555559125"
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "5555559150TO5555559175"
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = "5555559160"

TN = "5555559160"

For Each entry In Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
    If Len(entry.Value) = 10 And entry.Value = TN Then
        RowNo = entry.Row
        Debug.Print "RowNo = " & RowNo

    'Find beginning and ending values of a range
    ElseIf Len(entry.Value) > 10 And InStr(11, entry.Value, "TO") = 11 Then
        begin = CDbl(Left(entry.Value, 10))
        last = CDbl(Right(entry.Value, 10))

        'Search within range
        If CDbl(TN) >= begin And CDbl(TN) <= last Then
            RowNo = entry.Row
            Debug.Print "RowNo = " & RowNo
        End If
    End If
Next entry

End Sub
```